# Is there any framework to define more complex rules about powermanagement?

Tags: suspend, power-management

I the ubuntu settings, I can configure it that after e.g. 1 hour the computer goes to suspend (see screenshot at the bottom of this post).

My assumption is that this is determined on user activity (like: keyboard input; mouse is moved).

If I run a batch process or have a long lasting upload/download, I do not want to have the computer suspend.

Is there any framework or package where I can define more complex rules when to inhibit the system to suspend?

[image]

Comment: Would [caffeinate](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/caffeinate.1.html) give you what you need?

Comment: Yes, thanks, that looks promising. But I just realized, that it is not meant for headless operation, is it? I wonder whether I could make this working when logging into my (non 24/7) server via shell?